# Xamarin Android app with FCM crashing after killing and reopening again

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have successfully implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM)push notifications in my app. The app is able to receive notification when it is in the foreground and navigate to the respective activity. However when I kill the app and try to open again the app crashes.

**Here is my code of first activity i.e Splash activity:**

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Intent intent;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oStaticVariables.MembershipID))
        {
            intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LoginView));
        } 
        else
        {
            oStaticVariables.NewsListPreviousPosition = "";
            oStaticVariables.PTRShown = false;
            oStaticVariables.UpdateMsgShown = false;
            intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        }

            StartActivity(intent);
            Finish();
        CheckForBackgroundFCMNotifications();

    }


   *Fired when app is in background and the app receives notification*
    private void CheckForBackgroundFCMNotifications()
    {
        if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
            {
                var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                //Log.Debug("", "Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
                if (key == "NotifyId")
                {
                    oStaticVariables.GCMID = value;
                }
                if (key == "Header")
                {
                    oStaticVariables.GCMSubject = value;
                }
            }

            Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(NewsNotifications));
            StartActivity(nextActivity);

        }

    }
```

If I remove the CheckForBackgroundFCMNotifications() method the app does not crash after killing and reopening it. But I do need that method to fetch notification details and navigate to respective activity when the app is in the background.

Please help

Comment: What is the exception/stacktrace that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Without the stack trace we cant say for sure, but I'm pretty sure its either because you are launching an activity from an activity which has already finished or because you are launching two activities. Either way, you calling logic is wrong.

Check the intent for extras FIRST. then if there are extras, process them and start the appropriate activity (in your case NewsNotifications - BTW you should really call this NewsNotificationsActivity for naming consistency) and if not start the normal activity (in your case MainActivity).

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);    
        if (Intent.Extras == null)
        {   
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oStaticVariables.MembershipID))
            {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LoginView));
                StartActivity(intent);
            } 
            else
            {
                intent.PutExtra("NewsListPreviousPosition", "");
                intent.PutExtra("PTRShown", false);
                intent.PutExtra("UpdateMsgShown", false);
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                StartActivity(intent);
            }
            Finish();
        }
        else
        {
            CheckForBackgroundFCMNotifications();
        } 
    }

   // Called when app is in background and the app receives notification
    private void CheckForBackgroundFCMNotifications()
    {
         Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(NewsNotificationsActivity));
         foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
         {
                try  // just in case the value is not a string
                {
                    var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                    //Log.Debug("", "Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
                    if (key == "NotifyId")
                        nextActivity.PutExtra("NotifyId", value);
                    if (key == "Header")
                        nextActivity.PutExtra("Header", value);
                catch {}
        }
        StartActivity(nextActivity);
    }
```

Then pull the extra values out of the intent in MainActivity and NewsNotificationsActivity instead of from a static variable in a different activity.  You might also want to put the Extra extraction